# Set different volume for phone and clock

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, sound-volume, alarm

On iOS, is there a way to set a different volume (loudness level) for the alarms I set in the 'Clock' app?  I'd like to lower the volume for the alarm I use to wake up in the morning, but without lowering the volume for when I am on a call.  Right now I have to remember to turn down the ringer volume setting each night, then turn it back up when I am talking on the phone.

Can this be done?  I haven't found a way in the Settings app, but perhaps I'm just not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free application, called **Nightstand Central** (the one with the moon symbol) that lets you set the volume of the alarm as you like without changing that of the iPhone.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: make you own ringtone for alarm.

An iOS ringtone is a short (< 40s) m4a file in .m4r suffix.

Make it with audio editor (e.g. Audacity). Drag it to iPhone with iTunes.

In Audacity, Amplify with a negative value to reduce the loudness
[image: audacity amplify]

Answer (score 2):

For if the answer still hasn’t been found:

1. Go to the clock app
2. Click “edit” and press on the alarm you want to adjust (not the red button)
3. “Sound” and click on the song you want to use
4. As the sound plays, adjust your volume using the volume buttons

This should lower or rise the volume of your alarm without affecting your call ringtone.
Similarly, you can use this to adjust the volume of new alarms.

Comment: I just tested this and it DOES work. At least for the volume of the alarm, I didn't check if it reduces the phone call sound. Settings still says it's old value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of volume for iOS. They can all be adjusted with the two volume buttons (as long this is turned on in Settings>Sounds & Haptics>Change with Buttons).

The type of volume controlling your alarms is the Alert Volume. This can be changed by going to the **clock app** and adjusting volume. You will see a box **with a bell labeled "Ringer".**

The type of volume controlling your phone call volumes is a separate volume control that can be changed by **placing a call** (I just call myself) and using the volume buttons during the call. You will see a box **with a speaker labeled "Volume"**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the clock alarm volume changes if you lower the volume for videos, games, etc... unfortunately you need to remember to turn it back up after. Pretty stupid imo.